# How to get the group ID of a specific submodule?

Tags: gitlab

I'm a beginner with GitLab, I'm being asked to get the group ID of each submodule. But when I click on one for example, all I see is the Project ID.

Here we have a list of all submodules:

[image]

Clicking on RxAT1LGC submodule as an example:

[image]

Is there a way to get the group ID of each submodule?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [Get project API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/projects.html#get-single-project) (through curl or using the [`glab` CLI](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/integration/glab/)) in order to get the group of groups sharing that project:

```json
...

  "shared_with_groups": [
    {
      "group_id": 4,
      "group_name": "Twitter",
      "group_full_path": "twitter",
      "group_access_level": 30
    },
    {
      "group_id": 3,
      "group_name": "Gitlab Org",
      "group_full_path": "gitlab-org",
      "group_access_level": 10
    }
  ],
...
```